# DefaultMutableTreeNode-Text is too long?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have some DefaultMutableTreeNode's.
While the programm's running, I can change the text and revalidate it.
But if the text is too long, so for example the text "tested", the text will be displayed as "te...".

How do I change this ?

Thanks

Comment: if you are changing the text correctly, that is make sure the _model_ is notified the text should appear in full width, provided the tree width is big enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have to read [tutorial about JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display), and examples how to use [TreeCellRenderer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Tree-Renderer-Editor.htm)
- if you'll real question then please update your question and add there the code in [SSCCE form](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

the underlying reason is that the layout of the tree nodes is cached and the cache not updated properly. Might f.i. happen if the node is changed under feet of the model, uncomment the nodeChanged to see the difference

```
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    int index = 0;
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    String result = "\n";
    Enumeration<?> enumer = root.preorderEnumeration();
    while (enumer.hasMoreElements()) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) enumer.nextElement();
        String nodeValue = String.valueOf(node.getUserObject());
        node.setUserObject(nodeValue + ": " + index++);
       //model.nodeChanged(node);
    }
```

The exact reason in your context might vary, no way to tell without an sscce

Comment: Thank you but my problem was the cell width

Comment: Nope wrote my own cell-renderer, Thanks anyway!