# Resize of JTree node name when adding an icon dynamically after the tree has been generated

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treecellrenderer

In my code, depending on a condition,  a `JTree` node might or might not have an `Icon`.
My problem is when I want to set the `Icon` for a node, the size of the node's name is reduced and "***...***" are appended.

So basically, the node is recaulculating its size based on the icon size and fitting the rest.

How can I prevent this behavior and permit the node to expand its size when an icon is added?

Here is a screenshot of **without/with** icon:

[image]

Comment: `So basically, the node is recaulculating its size based on the icon size and fitting the rest.` --> not direct answer to your question without seeing [code that generated](http://sscce.org/) this issue(s), because by default ...., start with to check if all [TreeModelEvents are done correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7663094/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel I know that my question is not that well formed but when I wanted to write a test case, it turned out to be very long and so I thought maybe there was a general solution to this problem or maybe someone would guide me. If i do not find an answer, I will modify my question

Comment: after answer by @kleopatra +1 (!!!he recalculated size!!!), couldn't required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't know where you do it, but suspect you do it under the feet of the TreeModel: the LayoutCache does lots of .. well .. caching of sizes, so you have to make sure that it invalidates that cache. The only way to do so is via TreeModelEvents, something like (assuming the model is of type DefaultTreeModel):

```
myNodeData.setIcon(...);
treeModel.nodeChanged(node);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this code tomorrow. Actually I have my own `TreeNode` class in which I have an attribute called `iconName`. But I think that `treeModel.nodeChanged(node)` will do the trick as where I am setting the icon, I have access to the tree model.

Comment: Thanks man, the nodeChanged worked like a charm :) But I have a question, why are there two ways to fire events in a tree like `nodeChanged` and `fireTreeNodesChanged`

Comment: skip the "man" :-) the second is for internal usage, the first a convenience for external usage - not quite the best of designs (ideally, the model should always have complete control over its changes) but in the world of trees ...