# Dynamically increasing tree node width

Tags: java, treenode

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("View"); 
DefaultMutableTreeNode  p1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node-1");
DefaultMutableTreeNode  p2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node-2");
DefaultMutableTreeNode  p3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node-3");

treeNode.add(p1);
treeNode.add(p2);
treeNode.add(p3);
```

after execution of code
i want to increase the node with
from the above example i want change the p1 name dynamically.

```
enter code here
```

p1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("node-1123456");

treeNode.add(p1);

```
enter code here
```

it shows node-1.. like this.

Comment: I am not getting what error it shows ... please give us the specific error.

Comment: you Might want to check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662251/defaultmutabletreenode-text-is-too-long

Comment: not an error, node name it show uncompleted(node name (node-1123) but it shows node-... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

node.setUserObject(newName);